Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
This issue occurs when Jest fails to load SVG files.
The error details are as follows:
    Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    
    Check the render method of `TagInput`.
        at TagInput (/Users/newin/Desktop/homeCoding/deopjibhoeui/src/components/Input/TagInput.tsx:14:3)

      34 |                 onClick={() => removeTags(index)}
      35 |               >
    > 36 |                 <RemoveIcon />
         |                 ^
      37 |               </span>
      38 |             </li>
      39 |           ))}


The component containing  is defined as follows:
import React from 'react';
import styles from './TagInput.css';
import { ReactComponent as RemoveIcon } from '../../assets/svg/RemoveIcon.svg';
import { InputTag } from '../../core/hooks/types/useTagInput';

export interface TagInputProps {
  tags: InputTag[];
  addTags: (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  removeTags: (index: number) => void;
  placeholder?: string;
}

const TagInput = ({
  tags,
  addTags,
  removeTags,
  placeholder
}: TagInputProps) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles}>
      <div className="tags-input">
        <input
          className="tags-input-field"
          type="text"
          onKeyUp={(event) => (event.key === 'Enter' ? addTags(event) : null)}
          placeholder={placeholder}
        />
        <ul id="tags">
          {tags.map((tag, index) => (
            <li key={index} className="tag">
              <span className="tag-title">{tag}</span>
              <span
                className="tag-close-icon"
                onClick={() => removeTags(index)}
              >
                <RemoveIcon />
              </span>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TagInput;

Other configuration options are as follows:
Jest-config.json
{
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-transformer-svg"
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-transformer-svg",
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.css$": ["jest-transform-css", { "modules": true }]
  }
}

package.json
“devDependencies”: {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.24.7",
    "babel-jest": "27.5.1",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "27.5.1",
    "jest-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "jest-transform-css": "^6.0.1",
    "jest-transformer-svg": "^2.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
}

I know that Jest doesn't handle SVG files by default. So, I installed the jest-transformer-svg module, but the error did not go away.
How can this issue be resolved?
Here is a repository link where this error can be reproduced.
After downloading the repository, run yarn test after running yarn install.
https://github.com/ABlued/Deopjibhoeui
Expected behavior: the top error should not appear.
Current behavior: Top error appears

Jest doesn't handle SVGs directly, even though you've set up jest-transformer-svg. You could mock SVG imports during testing.
In your project root or src folder, create a mocks directory and inside that directory, create fileMock.js file.
Insder fileMock.js file add this.
module.exports = 'test-file-stub'

Now, you need to map SVG imports to your newly created mock file inside your Jest configuration. You should update the moduleNameMapper property like this:
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^.+\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
  "^.+\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
}

This will mock any SVG imports in your tests and replace them with a simple string.

Thank you for your response, I tried to follow what you taught me, but unfortunately, the error was not resolved.

Sorry for not giving you correct answer. Let me figure it out more..
